# Equivalent statements involving 'little o'

Tags: real-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and $a\in A$. 
$\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|=1+o(\frac{1}{z})$ as $z\rightarrow +\infty$ iff
$\|(z-a)^{-1}\|^{-1}=z+o(1)$ as $z\rightarrow +\infty$.
i.e.,
$lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\|(z-a)^{-1}\|^{-1}-z=0$ iff
 $lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|-1}{\frac{1}{z}}=0$.

One way follows easily.

Suppose $lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|-1}{\frac{1}{z}}=0$.

Then $lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|-1=0$
$\Rightarrow lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{\|(z-a)^{-1}\|}-z=0$
$\Rightarrow \|(z-a)^{-1}\|^{-1}=z+o(1)$ as $z\rightarrow +\infty$.

How does the converse follow? I would be grateful for a hint. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Here is what I've got- do let me know if this seems correct!

Suppose $\|(z-a)^{-1}\|^{-1}=z+o(1)$ as $z\rightarrow +\infty$.
i.e., $lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{\|(z-a)^{-1}\|}-z=0 \Rightarrow lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1-\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|}{\|(z-a)^{-1}\|}=0$
$\Rightarrow lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|-1}{\|(z-a)^{-1}\|}=0$.

Now $lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|-1}{\frac{1}{z}}=$
$lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|-1}{\|(z-a)^{-1}\|}\frac{\|(z-a)^{-1}\|}{\frac{1}{z}}$.

Consider $lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{\|(z-a)^{-1}\|}-z=0$, by hypothesis.

$\Rightarrow lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{z\|(z-a)^{-1}\|}=1$

Hence $lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|-1}{\frac{1}{z}}=0\cdot1=0$, as required.

Hence $\|z(z-a)^{-1}\|=1+o(\frac{1}{z})$ as $z\rightarrow +\infty$.